# Unable to connect win10 to linux nfs server

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, nfs

I am running a server with arch linux and it is for all intents and purposes an nfs server atm. It is up and running and everything works wonderfully. I am able to connect from both my laptops (running arch, and ubuntu) so I will assume for now that I was able to configure everything properly. The issue comes when trying to connect from my windows 10 machine. I have enabled the nfs client and what not in the **Turn on programs and features** (Not sure if thats actually the name or not).

From the command prompt...

```
$ mount -o anon \\ipAddr/home/user A: 
A: is now successfully connected to \\ipAddr/home/user
The command completed successfully.
$ A:
Access is denied
```

And from the file explorer, it tells me I have insufficient permissions to access the drive, and I need to contact the network admin. 
Also running mount yields

```
$ mount
Local    Remote                                 Properties
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
A:       \\ipAddr\home\user                  Unavailable
```

Does anyone have any ideas what my issue is?

Comment: have you tried `mountvol.exe \\ipAddr/home/user/ A:`? `mountvol.exe /?` might also help

Comment: hmm this gives me the error `The parameter is incorrect`

Comment: just tells me that mountvol.exe is a way to create list or delete volume mount points `Creates, deletes, or lists a volume mount point... MOUNTVOL [drive:] path... (ommited for brevity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decide to ditch windows' mount client and switch to sshfs as this is what I am used to and my preferred method of mounting and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

- Start **regedit**
- Locate
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default`
- Add two DWORD values:
  AnonymousUid, AnonymousGid
- enter "**1000**" `decimal` base.
  [regedit values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGQBr.png)
- restart NFS service or reboot pc.
- Open Computer and Click the Map netwok drive button on the toolbar.
- Enter `HostIP:/share` on the Folder text box.
- Click Finish.

*If you encounter an error;*

- Enter `HostIP/share` on the Folder text box.
- Click Finish.